# SyntaxError: JSON5: invalid character 'm' at 3:1

Tags: configuration, babeljs, babel-loader, json5

Babel is giving me the following error:

```
../../node_modules/next/dist/pages/_error.js
SyntaxError: JSON5: invalid character 'm' at 3:1
```

My `.babelrc` and `babel.config.cjs`:

```
/* eslint-disable no-template-curly-in-string */

module.exports = {
  presets: [['next/babel']],
  plugins: [
    [
      'babel-plugin-transform-imports',
      {
        lodash: {
          transform: 'lodash/${member}',
          preventFullImport: true,
        },
        '@mui/material': {
          transform: '@mui/material/${member}',
          preventFullImport: true,
        },
        '@mui/icons-material': {
          transform: '@mui/icons-material/${member}',
          preventFullImport: true,
        },
        '@mui/lab': {
          transform: '@mui/lab/${member}',
          preventFullImport: true,
        },
<snip>
```

Comment: My answer is most likely too late for you, but I figured other people might run into similar errors not knowing that `.babelrc` is expected to be in JSON5 format. I have some other tips for you in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [babel *Config Files* documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#supported-file-extensions):

> `.babelrc` is an alias for `.babelrc.json`

and

> `babel.config.json` and `.babelrc.json` are parsed as JSON5 and should contain an object...

The error message you are getting confirms this: Babel is parsing the file as JSON5 and beginning on line 3 column 1 the content is not valid JSON5. If you remove the `module.exports =`  from that line, the error will be fixed.

(I cannot tell whether you have other errors in you `.babelrc` since you didn't not present the entire file. Once you fix the above line you'll find out.)

On the other hand, your file `babel.config.cjs` is expected to be valid Javascript, you would need to retain the `module.exports =` . Or you could rename it to `babel.config.json` and use the same format as your `.babelrc`.

You may also want to rename your `.babelrc` to `.babelrc.json` to make its format explicit in its name.